# triggering an Automator flow when a sound is played

Tags: audio, automator

i use a chrome extension that plays a 'bing' when changes are made to a website that it's monitoring. this is the only sound that OS X will produce. is there any way to get output of a sound to trigger an automator script? i plan on then setting something up that could send me an email (or notification) to my iphone.

Comment: How in-depth does this check need to be? Will checking for the modification date of the webpage be enough? I ask because checking for an update and performing the action within the same script is much more reliable.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Its a Facebook page that I'm following and I want as close to immediate notifications of any updates as possible. Facebook notifications are too slow, (between 4-10 mins) and Facebook emails are even slower (~20mins). So ideally I'm looking for a solution that is under 4 minutes to see an improvement. Under 1 minute would be ideal. I'm not sure if the Facebook 'page' would have a modification date?